# Java - Programa para contar caracteres repetidos

Tags: java, bucle-for, caracteres

soy estudiante de programación necesito hacer una actividad que colocando una frase cualquiera por scanner, por ejemplo "hola que tal", me diga cuantas letras de cada tipo en la frase introducida hay en total, por ejemplo:

> Tienes 1 letra h
>
> Tienes 1 letra o
>
> Tienes 2 letras l
>
> Tienes 2 letras a
>
> Tienes 1 letra q
>
> Tienes 1 letra u
>
> Tienes 1 letra e
>
> Tienes 1 letra t

He mirado por internet y he intentado hacer mi propio codigo pero no me aclaro para nada y no me da el resultado que estoy buscando.

este es mi codigo

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Act4 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Introduce una frase: ");
        String frase = lector.nextLine();

        contarCaracteres(frase);

        lector.close();
    }

    public static void contarCaracteres(String frase) {
        int contador = 0, y = 0;
        char [] abecedario = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

        for(int x=0;x<abecedario.length;x++) {
            for(y = 0;y<frase.length();y++) {
                if ((frase.charAt(y)==abecedario[x])){
                        contador++;

                        System.out.println("La letra "+x+" tiene "+contador+" letras");
                }
                else if((frase.charAt(y)==abecedario[x] && y !=(abecedario[x]))) {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El problema de mi codigo es que me dice cual es la posición de la letra directamente sin devolverme la letra y me repite la letra diciendome una por una hasta el valor maximo de letras.

```
Introduce una frase: 
hola que tal
La letra 0 tiene 1 letras
La letra 0 tiene 2 letras
La letra 4 tiene 3 letras
La letra 7 tiene 4 letras
La letra 11 tiene 5 letras
La letra 11 tiene 6 letras
La letra 14 tiene 7 letras
La letra 16 tiene 8 letras
La letra 19 tiene 9 letras
La letra 20 tiene 10 letras
```

Alguien me puede ayudar ? gracias de antemano.

Edito:
He introducido abecedario[x] en vez de x sola y ya me saca la letra deseada, pero solo me falta juntar las letras en una.

`System.out.println("La letra "+abecedario[x]+" tiene "+contador+" letras");`

este es el resultado ahora

```
Introduce una frase: 
hola que tal
La letra a tiene 1 letras
La letra a tiene 2 letras
La letra e tiene 3 letras
La letra h tiene 4 letras
La letra l tiene 5 letras
La letra l tiene 6 letras
La letra o tiene 7 letras
La letra q tiene 8 letras
La letra t tiene 9 letras
La letra u tiene 10 letras
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contador` es la variable en la que guardas las veces que aparece cada letra
en la frase, pero al definirla fuera del primer *for* es "compartida" en todo
el ciclo. Lo que tendrias que hacer es definirla al principio del primer *for*:

```
for(int x=0;x<abecedario.length;x++) {
    int contador = 0;
    // ...
}
```

Con ese cambio muestra lo siguiente:

```
Introduce una frase:
arrastrar
La letra a tiene 1 letras
La letra a tiene 2 letras
La letra a tiene 3 letras
La letra r tiene 1 letras
La letra r tiene 2 letras
La letra r tiene 3 letras
La letra r tiene 4 letras
La letra s tiene 1 letras
La letra t tiene 1 letras
```

¿Por qué no muestra un solo mensaje para cada letra?

El `println` está dentro del ciclo *for* que cuenta las veces que aparece una letra
en la frase, entonces se repite cada vez que encuentra una letra. Tendrías que
sacarlo del *for* y ponerlo después de contar:

```
for(y = 0;y<frase.length();y++) {
    // ...
}

System.out.println("La letra "+abecedario[x]+" tiene "+contador+" letras");
```

Y esto nos da:

```
Introduce una frase:
arrastrar
La letra a tiene 3 letras
La letra b tiene 0 letras
La letra c tiene 0 letras
La letra d tiene 0 letras
La letra e tiene 0 letras
La letra f tiene 0 letras
La letra g tiene 0 letras
La letra h tiene 0 letras
La letra i tiene 0 letras
La letra j tiene 0 letras
La letra k tiene 0 letras
La letra l tiene 0 letras
La letra m tiene 0 letras
La letra n tiene 0 letras
La letra o tiene 0 letras
La letra p tiene 0 letras
La letra q tiene 0 letras
La letra r tiene 4 letras
La letra s tiene 1 letras
La letra t tiene 1 letras
La letra u tiene 0 letras
La letra v tiene 0 letras
La letra w tiene 0 letras
La letra x tiene 0 letras
La letra y tiene 0 letras
La letra z tiene 0 letras
```

Como no nos interesa las letras que aparecen cero veces tenemos que encerrar
al `println` en un *if*

```
if (contador > 0) {
    System.out.println("La letra "+abecedario[x]+" tiene "+contador+" letras");
}
```

Y nos da el resultado esperado.

```
Introduce una frase:
arrastrar
La letra a tiene 3 letras
La letra r tiene 4 letras
La letra s tiene 1 letras
La letra t tiene 1 letras
```

Otra cosa, el mensaje "La letra r tiene 4 letras", no tiene mucho sentido.
Sería mejor que imprima algo parecido a "La frase tiene 4 letras r".

Y esta parte del código no sé que aporta y creo que se puede sacar:

```
if((frase.charAt(y)==abecedario[x] && y !=(abecedario[x]))) {
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! tu comentario ha sido muy util he podido terminar mi codigo! y me has ayudado a comprender donde estaba equivocandome, me he dado cuenta que no estaba lejos del resultado pero que tenia muchas cosas fuera de lugar.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error reside en que usas el mismo contador para todas las letras, entonces lo que realmente estás haciendo es ir contando cuantas letras tiene la frase pasada por teclado.

Siguiendo tu forma de hacerlo, puedes hacer un vector de 26 posiciones inicializándolas todas a 0. Este vector marcará cuantas veces ha aparecido cada letra en la cadena introducida.

Una forma más correcta de hacerlo puede ser utilizando el tabla ASCII. Puedes buscar sobre ella en [esta página](https://www.asciitable.com/) o buscando en google. No se si estás familiarizado con esta tabla, pero es algo básico de la programación. Un char corresponde a un número entero, por ejemplo, el carácter `a` corresponde al número 97, por lo que si restamos 97 a un char nos dará su posición en el vector que nos marca todas las letras del abecedario por orden. (Puedes aplicar operaciones a los char también).

Quedaría este código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Act4 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Introduce una frase: ");
        String frase = lector.nextLine();

        contarCaracteres(frase);

        lector.close();
    }

    public static void contarCaracteres(String frase) {
        int y = 0;
        int vecesLetra[];
        vecesLetra = new int[26];

        for(y = 0; y<frase.length(); y++) {
            // Está en el abecedario y no es otro carácter como un espacio
            if((int)frase.charAt(y) >= 97 && (int)frase.charAt(y)<=172)
                vecesLetra[ (int)frase.charAt(y)-97 ]++;

        }

        for(y=0 ; y < vecesLetra.length; y++){
            if(vecesLetra[y]>0){
                System.out.println("La palabra "+(char)(y+97)+" tiene "+vecesLetra[y]+" letras");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Con este resultado:

```
Introduce una frase: 
hola que tal
La palabra a tiene 2 letras
La palabra e tiene 1 letras
La palabra h tiene 1 letras
La palabra l tiene 2 letras
La palabra o tiene 1 letras
La palabra q tiene 1 letras
La palabra t tiene 1 letras
La palabra u tiene 1 letras
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por ayudarme! tu codigo es genial y muy profesional, pero he sentido que no saldría de mi hacerlo de ese modo, ya que la forma de escritura no alcanza a mi nivel aún, de todas formas, me ha parecido super util y de mucha ayuda la explicación sobre el codigo ASCII, lo tomaré en cuenta para el futuro.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Map<Character, Integer> guardaValoresCharRepetidos(char[] caracteres)
{
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (char keyCaracter: caracteres) {
        map.put(keyCaracter, map.getOrDefault(keyCaracter, 0) + 1);
    }

    return map;
}

private static int cuentaRepetidos(Map<Character, Integer> map, char caracter) {
    return map.get(caracter);
}

private static Set<String> eliminaDuplicados(char[] caracteres){
    Set<String> duplicados = new HashSet<String>();

    for(int i=1; i <= (caracteres.length -1); i++ ) {
        duplicados.add(String.valueOf(caracteres[i]));
                    
     }
    return duplicados;
}



public static void resultadoCuentaCaracteres() {
    String str = "ABAACBDDRRRR";
     
    Map<Character, Integer> map = guardaValoresCharRepetidos(str.toCharArray());
    
    char[] caracteres = str.toCharArray();
    
    Set<String> duplicados =eliminaDuplicados(caracteres);
    
    for(String indexDuplicado :duplicados) {
    
    try {
        
    char caracter =indexDuplicado.charAt(indexDuplicado.length() -1);
    
    System.out.println("Caracter " + caracter + " se repite " +  cuentaRepetidos(map,  caracter) + " veces.");
    }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        
        System.out.print(ex);
        
    }
 


}
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Answer (score 0):

Map<String, Long> counted =Stream.of(cadenaArray)
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

```
    System.out.println("Conteo repetidos =>"+ counted);
    List<String> cadenaSinRepetidos = Stream.of(cadenaArray).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    System.out.println("Duplicados eliminados =>"+ cadenaSinRepetidos);
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).